# How to customize page numbering as "Chapter number + page number" in book class?

Tags: sectioning, page-numbering, front-matter

I am writing my final thesis, and I want to change the default page numbering like (also in TOC):

```
1. Introduction             1-1
   1.1 Background ......... 1-1
   1.1 Object ......... ... 1-2
   1.1 Outline ............ 1-4

2. State of the art         2-1
   2.1 Introduction ....... 2-1
   2.1 Blabla ......... ... 2-4
   2.1 Blabla ............. 2-18

  ...

Reference                   R-1
Appendix A                  A-1
Appendix B                  A-3
```

where `R` and `A` stand for `Reference` and `Appendix` respectively.

Using `fancyhdr`:

```
\fancyhead[LE]{ \thechapter - \thepage }
\fancyhead[RO]{ \thechapter - \thepage }
```

Where  number 5 is the first page of chapter 2 and it should be `2-1`, the second page number should be like `2-2` instead of `2-6`. Besides, the Roman page number in `frontmatter` becomes like `0-XV` etc.

[image]

I have been looking through some relevant posts, but all of them can not solve this issue.

What I want is to make the whole document page numbering as `Chapter No. + page No.` staring with `chapter No. + 1`, and use the default Roman number for `frontmatter` pages `without chapter No.`

So how to figure this out?

Comment: `\renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{page}}`

Comment: the [chappg](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chappg) package does this for you (and deals with a number of consequent edge effects).

Comment: @wasteofspace Make that an answer, please.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I tried but it does not work.

Comment: @KOF You *don't* really want that, do you?

Comment: `\renewcommand\thepage{\arabic{chapter}-\arabic{page}}`  not work with `book` class, just for `article` or `report` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redefine `\thepage` at the start of `\mainmatter`, and change the definition of the internal `\@chapter` macro so that it will also reset the page counter to 1 if the `mainmatter` switch is true. (Note that `\clearpage`/`\cleardoublepage` is called before `\@chapter`.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto{\mainmatter}{\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
% If \backmatter is used
\appto{\backmatter}{%
  \renewcommand*{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}%
  \setcounter{page}{1}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

\lipsum[1-3]

\mainmatter

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{gnu}

\section{gnugnat}

\lipsum[1-12]

\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{R-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}% optional

% "Fake" Bibliography chapter
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}
\appendix

\chapter{appfoo}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}​
```

EDIT: Here's an alternative if you insist on manually "numbering" your appendix chapters. Also note that your updated page numbering scheme is inconsistent (some, but not all chapters start with page [Prefix-]1).

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\appto{\mainmatter}{\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\if@mainmatter}{\if@mainmatter\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Preface}

\lipsum[1-3]

\mainmatter

\chapter{foo}

\section{foobar}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{gnu}

\section{gnugnat}

\lipsum[1-12]

\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{R-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}% optional

% "Fake" Bibliography chapter
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{A01} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\cleardoublepage
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{A-\arabic{page}}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\backmatter

\chapter{Appendix~A}

\lipsum[1-12]

\chapter{Appendix~B}

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. By the way, can you please add the numbering `Reference` and `Appendix` for `backmatter`. For `Reference` no chapter name, and for `Appendix A/B` it's like A-1, A-2.... B-1, B-2...

Comment: @KOF Does the "Reference" chapter appear before the appendix chapters? In that case, one should use a numbering scheme like "Ref-1" for the sake of consistency.

Comment: `Reference` is before `backmatter`, while  `Appendix` is after `backmatter`. There is also a minor issue, the heading of Appendix is like: `Chapter  Appendix A`, where `Appendix A` is the Appendix name, How to get ride of the `Chapter` ?

Comment: @KOF It's unclear why you use `\backmattter` at all. I will update my answer to include "Reference"  plus appendices. Maybe my solution will also be sufficient for the "Chapter"  prefix problem -- note that this is a different question (with existing answers at tex.sx).

Comment: @lockstep How can I add the last page in the appendix? instead of having A1, I would like o have A1/totalpages. could you help me please? I have this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/665131/how-to-restart-the-page-numbering-in-each-appendix?noredirect=1#comment1653919_665131) opened