# How to restart the page numbering in each appendix

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr, appendix

I would like to change the start numbering in each appendix, with the code below, I keep the numbering from the last section. For example, I would like to have A1/9, A2/9, and when I start a new appendix the page numbering restarts like B1/9, B2/9. How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[
   numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{lipsum}


%%%% Chapter Stylus

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  font=\normalsize
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  font=\Large,beforeskip=0pt
]{chapter}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\chapterformat{\autodot}{.}{}{\PatchFailed}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithdot
]{chapter}{chapter}
\newcommand*\entrynumberwithdot[1]{\def\autodot{.}#1}


%%%%%% Foot and Header


\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\lhead{\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont {IMAGE 1 \\   \quad IMAGE 2 } }

\rhead{IMAGE 3}

\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\chapter{Methodology}

\lipsum

\appendix
\fancyfoot[R]{\thechapter\thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}


\chapter{Data}

\lipsum

\chapter{Tables}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304029/change-the-page-numbering-of-appendices-and-restart-it

Comment: My document class is scrreprt, while in the example is scrartcl (chapters not allowed). I can't change my document class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This adds a new counter `relpage` so that `\fancyfoot` can use `\therelpage` instead of `\thepage`.  Note that it resets to 0 instead of 1, hense the `\numexpr`.

```
\documentclass[
   numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{lastpage}% redundant
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{lipsum}


%%%% Chapter Stylus

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  font=\normalsize
]{section,subsection,subsubsection}

\RedeclareSectionCommands[
  font=\Large,beforeskip=0pt
]{chapter}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\chapterformat{\autodot}{.}{}{\PatchFailed}

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entrynumberwithdot
]{chapter}{chapter}
\newcommand*\entrynumberwithdot[1]{\def\autodot{.}#1}


%%%%%% Foot and Header


\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\lhead{\fontsize{6pt}{6pt}\selectfont {IMAGE 1 \\   \quad IMAGE 2 } }

\rhead{IMAGE 3}

\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage / \pageref{LastPage}}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcounter{relpage}[chapter]
\renewcommand{\therelpage}{\thechapter\the\numexpr\value{relpage}+1\relax}
\AddToHook{shipout/after}{\stepcounter{relpage}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\chapter{Methodology}

\lipsum

\appendix
\chapter*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}%
\fancyfoot[R]{\therelpage / \pageref{LastPage}}%

\chapter{Data}

\lipsum

\chapter{Tables}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you so much =)